# How to find last items of order to get its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of order:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\left(\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2n+3}-\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2n-1}\right)$$

There is how they count it in book:

$$s_{n} = \left(\frac{3}{10}-\frac{3}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{14}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{3}{10}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{22}-\frac{3}{14}\right)+...+\left(\frac{3}{4n-2}-\frac{3}{4n-10}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{4n+2}-\frac{3}{4n-6}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{4n+6}-\frac{3}{4n-2}\right)$$
$$s_{n} = \frac{-3}{2}+\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{3}{4n+2}+\frac{3}{4n+6}$$
$$s = \lim_{n->∞}s_{n} = \lim_{n->∞}\left [\frac{-3}2 - \frac12 + \frac3{4n+2} + \frac3{4n+6}\right ] = -2$$

I understand how to solve the lim, I just dont understand, how to get those last items from order, I mean this items:

$$\left(\frac{3}{4n-2}-\frac{3}{4n-10}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{4n+2}-\frac{3}{4n-6}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{4n+6}-\frac{3}{4n-2}\right)$$

---

**UPDATE**

Now I understand how to get those "last" items. But I'm confused now, why are they even in the sum inside of lim of $s_n$? If I would keep counting next items, they would get canceled. For example, there is $\frac3{4n+2}$ in $s_n$, if I count n+1 item, this would get canceled. So why do we count them in $s_n$ if only first two fractals {$\frac{-3}2, \frac12 $} couldn't be canceled (if not thinking of negative n).
Could anyone explain please?

Comment: I have used this editor: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php for equations, sorry ... how to fix them?

Comment: Your $\LaTeX$ was fine, you only didn't take any environments, so Mathjax didn't know what to render

Comment: @Buksy: You just needed to wrap everything in dollar signs, `$...math stuff...$`, or double dollar signs to use "display" mode `$$...math stuff...$$`.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: There should be a $+ \cdots$ to indicate that the sequence continues. Those are not the "last" items; it is an attempt to show which terms cancel when the sequence telescopes down.

Comment: There is a common factor of $\frac{3}{2}$ in all the terms. Take it out: typing gets easier. More importantly, it will make the structure clearer.

Comment: Thank you all, could you please take a look at my update?

Comment: Should I create new question for my update to this question or is it ok keep it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i didn't missunterstood your question, this sum is a so called telescoping sum, the other terms are canceled so you only have those left which are mentioned.

Those are

\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{4n-10}&= \frac{3}{4(n-1)-6}\\
\frac{3}{4n-6}&= \frac{3}{4(n-1)-2} \\
\end{align*}
And $$\frac{3}{4n-2}$$ is canceled from the last paranthesis.

Comment: Thank you, but in first fractal there should be either n-2 "3/[4(n-2)-2] = 3/[4n-10]" or +6 "3/[4(n-1)+6] = 3/[4n+2]"

Comment: Could you please take a look at me update to question?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 terms you have mentioned above saying you didnot understand are the (n-2),(n-1) and nth terms of that series.

So if you just substitute 'n' with 'n-2' you get : $$\frac{3}{4n-2} - \frac{3}{4n-10}$$

if you substitute 'n' with 'n-1' you get : $$\frac{3}{4n+2} - \frac{3}{4n-6}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the update:  If you look at the denominators, the first fraction goes $5,7,9,11,\ldots$  The second fraction goes $1,3,5,7,9\ldots$  As they enter with opposite signs, all the matching ones can be canceled with one from the other set.  We are left with just $1$ and $3$.  Because these are in the deominators, that is what becomes $\frac {-\frac 32}1 + \frac {-\frac 32}3=-2$.  This is commonly true for telescoping sums.  The surviving terms are the first few, which are not canceled.  All the rest vanish through cancellation.

Comment: So, can I just ignore "last" terms (if I know they will get canceled) and count only with first?

Comment: @Buksy:  That is right.  You also have to figure out which ones don't get canceled..